# I want to show the child category name not the parent category name

Tags: wordpress

```
  <div class="careerleft">

   <?php query_posts('cat=9&paged='.get_query_var('paged')); ?>

   <?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

   <div <?php post_class() ?> id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>">

   <p class="career">"><?php the_title(); ?></p>

   <p>Category: <?php single_cat_title()?></p>

   <p>Date posted:<?php the_time('F j, Y') ?></p>

   </div>

   <?php endwhile; ?>

   <?php else : ?>

  <h2>Not Found</h2>


  <?php endif; ?>


 </div>
```

I want to show the child category name, but when I used the , it only shows the parent category name. In my categories, the parent category name is "careers", and this category has 3 child category names which are Managerial, IT Related and Accounting. What will be the code to show the child category name?

Answer (score 0):

here you have to extract the child categories first . See how to extract [Wordpress Categories](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_categories).

Extract all the categories of the parent category

`<?php $args = array(
    'type'                     => 'post',
    'parent'                   => 9,
    'taxonomy'                 => 'category'
     );?>`

`<?php $categories = get_categories( $args ); ?>`

After extracting all the categories create aloop to print them